# Unicode tricks and hacks, vertical text, Non spacing marks

Tags: unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes, zalgo

I ran into some vertical text that overflowed on a popular site which surprised me and thought it was some sort of code injection.

```
!̸̶͚͖͖̩̻̩̗͍̮̙̈͊͛̈͒̍̐ͣͩ̋ͨ̓̊̌̈̊́̚͝͠ͅ
```

> When I select it its like one character .. when I hit backspace its like tens of characters.. what is going on?!
>
> Here it is outside a code block.

!̸̶͚͖͖̩̻̩̗͍̮̙̈͊͛̈͒̍̐ͣͩ̋ͨ̓̊̌̈̊́̚͝͠ͅ

According to HTML entity encoder/decoder at https://mothereff.in/html-entities , it decodes to this:

```
!&#x338;&#x336;&#x35A;&#x356;&#x356;&#x329;&#x33B;&#x329;&#x317;&#x34D;&#x32E;&#x319;&#x308;&#x34A;&#x35B;&#x308;&#x352;&#x30D;&#x310;&#x363;&#x369;&#x30B;&#x368;&#x313;&#x30A;&#x30C;&#x308;&#x30A;&#x301;&#x31A;&#x35D;&#x360;&#x345;
```

If you remove the preceding `!` then it spreads out.. what's going on with this craziness?